# Serialize a map that doesn't have a string as a key with lift-json

Tags: scala, serialization, dictionary, lift-json

It seems like lift-json is limited to maps that have Strings as keys.

What is the best way to bypass this limitation ?

Comment: Aren't JSON objects limited to have only strings for keys?

Comment: Yes, JSON objects are limited to have only strings for keys. They are, as a practical matter, the method names, so it's fitting.

Comment: Yes, my question was how can you (de)serialize map that haven't string as key since there is this limitation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your own `Serializer[Map[Any, Any]]`.

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import ext._

object MapSerializer extends Serializer[Map[Any, Any]] {
  def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
    case m: Map[_, _] => JObject(m.map({
      case (k, v) => JField(
        k match {
          case ks: String => ks
          case ks: Symbol => ks.name
          case ks: Any => ks.toString
        },
        Extraction.decompose(v)
      )
    }).toList)
  }

  def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Map[Any, Any]] = {
    sys.error("Not interested.")
  }
}
```

Then add it to the implicit `Formats` variable.

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + MapSerializer
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer you can define instead:

def deserialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), Map[Any, Any]] = {
    Map()
  }

This doesn't break any other working map deserialization.